# Adding a Dynamic Title in Print Composer

Tags: print-composer, dynamic-text

I am using QGIS 3.4.2 for a project with several layers, and a print composer with a generic legend for all. I would like to add a dynamic map title, that states the name of the displayed layer(s) only. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: you can add an text field, insert an expression and use @layer_name, is this what you want?

Comment: What I would want, is that based on the layers actually displayed on the map, the map title adjusts automatically - displaying automatically, the name of the displayed layer as a map title. Is that possible?